# How to apply CSS roles from browser console

Tags: javascript

Is it doable to apply some CSS roles from Browser Console like this?

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

I tried this but I am getting following error

[image]

Comment: It seems there is no element with that ID

Comment: I have for sure a div with `#myDIV` id in the document

Comment: Yes, that should work as is. I think the issue here is that your ID case is wrong. It has to be identical. For example, if your div ID is `<div id="mydiv">`, then you have to write it as `mydiv` rather than `myDIV`.

Edit: On second look, this doesn't look like your issue, but my point remains valid for anyone else with this issue who sees this.

Comment: please share the HTML

Comment: It will also probably not work if the element is dynamically-injected into the page.

Comment: That's actually true. it is dynamically added element

Comment: It should work even if it is dynamically injected but in this case brk is right, your element doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it was dynamically injected. Perhaps it's in an iframe?